# Refresh webpage when "#" is there in URL

Tags: url, refresh, html, durandal

I have one Durandal application and in that every view gets rendered with "#{ViewName}"in the URL. Now the issue is, at this time if user keeps the cursor in address bar and hits the "Enter" button then the page is not reloaded. How to achieve that?
The reason why it is not loaded is known that it tries to find element with that #id in the page. But my question is how to reload by hitting Enter in address bar?

Comment: Refresh page either through reload button or keyboard shortcut. If you want to do it via code let me know.

Comment: Yes as mentioned in the question, we need to handle in code. The requirement is specific that on hitting "Enter" button the page should reload when there is "#" in the URL.

Comment: try `window.location.reload(true);` this will forcefully reload the browser window.

Answer (score 0):

Try below script whenever you want to reload page through code.

```
window.location.reload(true);
```

Comment: window.location.reload() - How do you call when enter is pressed at Address bar? Please check my question completely. Appreciate your replies but both of your replies doesn't point to the scenario which I mentioned.